# FirefoxOS calling WebActivity "share" doesn't show menu of the web activities

Tags: javascript, firefox, android-activity, firefox-os

I am writing mobile application which will allow to upload images on external server (via share activity) but also setting as a wallpaper image from the external service, or just social network share same image.

In my application I have defined both share and pick activities (pick to provide pictures to other apps, and share -  to upload on external service).

However, having declared by myself "share" activity I am not able to share picture to other app.

I have following piece of code:

```
$('#sharePicture').click(function() {
  var activity = new MozActivity({
    name: "share",
    data: {
      type: ["image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/bmp"],
    }
  });
});
```

and I expect it to show menu of web activities to choose application to perform share activity.

Unfortunately, nothing like this happen - and what I am getting instead is a content of a "***share-activity.html***" page.

I guess that it happens because I have declared in my application also handler for the "share" activity (this is a mobile client for https://picup.it hosting platform). However, for some reason I am not getting a menu of webactivities - and what worse - performing **share** activity from my own application, which makes vicious circle.

```
 "activities": {
        "share": {
      "href": "./share-activity.html",
      "disposition": "inline",
      "filters": {
        "type": ["image/*","image/jpeg","image/png"]
      },
      "returnValue": false
    },
    "pick": {
      "href": "./pick-activity.html",
      "disposition": "inline",
      "filters": {
        "type": ["image/*","image/jpeg","image/png"]
      },
      "returnValue": true
    }
  },
```

How I can define correctly handle for "***share activitiy***" and how I can use correctly to delegate sharing to external application? Right now they overlap.

I have uploaded example application which presents this unexpepcted behaviour: https://github.com/bluszcz/webactivity-bug-993321

Comment: I have submitted bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=993321

Answer (score 0):

Why you set a filter for all image type and after require specific format?
The first "image/*" cover all the format.
I have found this example app for imgur https://github.com/soapdog/firefoxos-sample-app-image-uploader , the manifest it's the same of your. You are sure of the update in the simulator?

Comment: I have tried in the simulator, but I test mostly on real device (ZTE Open 1.3). Regarding imgur - application provides handler for activity "share", but it delegates only "pick" activity. In my application I want to share also picture from my application to other application...